# Как передать массив с сервера в клиентский Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть текст и в каждом ряде значения.И мне надо било бы зделать из него массив  в Javascript на стороне клиента.У меня есть 3 предпологаемых мной варианта решения. 
Что из етого реализуемо?
Вариант 1
а)Создать на сервере тестовый файл.
б) Както прочесть его(средствами Javascript на стороне клиента).
В) Сделать с него массив(в Javascript на стороне клиента).
Вариант 2
а)Создать какойто textarea с етим текстом,и сховать его.
б) Както прочесть его(средствами Javascript на стороне клиента).
В) Сделать с него массив(в Javascript на стороне клиента).
Вариант 3
а)Создать массив в PHP.
б)Както передать его в Javascript на стороне клиента.

Вариант4
А)Создать масив Javascript на стороне клиента ,в нужних страничках.

Предполагаю, но незнаю можно ли так сделать.Вариант 4 как знаю,но  ето плохой вариант. 
Мне интересен 3 вариант.

Comment: Средствами javascript на сервере или средствами javascript у клиента?

Comment: читать чем файл будете ? что значит преобразовать в массив ? по строкам разбить ? текстовый файл можно запросить ajax запросом, потом с этим файлом что угодно делайте [вот дока](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: еще раз что значит массив из текста ? реализуемо все.

Comment: JavaScript пишется вместе,

Comment: еще раз что значит массив из текста ?реализуемо все.  
А как созданый в PHP массив в Javascript  засунуть?

Comment: @eicto, это ужас. Представляете какая каша потом будет у человека на сайте и в голове после этого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых: используйте jQuery, для вас он будет самый раз

Во вторых: посмотрите на JSON, в php для него есть [фукции](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.json.php)

после воспользуйтесь кодом

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/array_in_json.dat',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(ans){
        // тут в ans будет ваш массив
        window.array=ans;
    }
})
```

по методу [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

в `array` будет ваш массив

вместо `array_in_json.dat` можно использовать серверный скрипт который будет генерировать нужный массив

вызов вышеприведённого кода выполняете после загрузки сраницы, например по `$(document).ready()` или `window.onload`

---

P.S. если приведённые варианты решений вы нагуглили и поняли, либо сами до такого догадались. Думаю вам стоит разобраться в примере и плотнее занятся вебом

Comment: Спасибо,буду разбираться.С jQuery и ajax незнаком ,но теперь есть повод чтоб разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

на сторое php формируете массив вида:

```
{"countPage":1,"name":"text"}
```

например по адресу getData.php

дальше дело в JS
например с помощью JQuery (нужно будет подключить скрипт)

```
function parseJSON(parJSON)
{
    //если переданный параметр - строка (а то мало ли)
    if(typeof parJSON == "string"){
        //начинаем парсит JSON
        //если браузер поддерживает встроенный JSON, то используем его. Если нет (IE6-7) то используем eval
        return window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ? JSON.parse(parJSON) : eval('('+parJSON+')'); 
    }
    return parJSON;
}    
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.get('getData.php', '', function (dat) {
   var x=parseJSON(dat);
   var CPage=x.countPage;
}
```

функция **parseJSON** преобразует текстовый вариант в объект JS

**jQuery.get** - посылает Get запрос на страничку, сгенерированную страницу получает в **dat**

Comment: Ваш ответ верный ,но Gedweb ответил раньше и галочка ему). Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

правильный ответ, имхо, уже дан - запрашивать данные от серверного скрипта через аякс, я же предложу костыльный черезжопный вариант, для разнообразия:

```
    <script>
    var arr=[<? echo $my_arr[0].",".$my_arr[1].",".$my_arr[2]; ?>];
    // вот таким вот жутким вариантом можно передать простые переменные из пхп в жс
    // ограничения - сложности с большими объемами, все переменные открыты, их легко можно прочесть
    // с точки зрения отладки взаимодействия - сойдет, но пароли так передавать не нужно...
    </script>
```

т.е. в страницу, которую формирует пхп, можно подставить кусок кода джаваскрипт, в который скрипт пхп "впечатает" нужные данные

Comment: Я тоже про такоє думал.Но все что на скрипте "все переменные открыты, их легко можно прочесть" и изменить.Но как черневой вариант сойдет)

Comment: Если делать так, тогда уж лучше:

   var arr = <?= json_encode( $my_arr ) ?>;